# CAML Query Cannot Complete This Action

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to just test this out by running these two commands (after connecting) from the command prompt and I'm constantly getting a "Cannot complete this action." error message with no further details about what or why.

```
$caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRefName='HostName'/><Eq><Value Type='Text'>myservername</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
$list = Get-PnPListItem -List ServerInventory_Official-List -Query $caml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query is not constructed correctly try this instead:

```
//with your param
$caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRefName='HostName'/><Value Type='Text'>" + myservername + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

//without param
$caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRefName='HostName'/><Value Type='Text'>myservername</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

you had an extra `<Eq>` in there.

Comment: Actually yeah I tried removing that extra Eq and it resulted in an error saying " One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these" -OR- it gives an error saying that the value does not fall within expected range.